# Do we need to Re-create Model Classes while using the Repository Pattern

Tags: wpf, mvvm, repository-pattern

I'm using the LinqtoSQL for a WPF M-V-VM application, as I might want to change from LinqtoSql to something else in the future, like Entity framework or Subsonic etc, thus I found repository pattern to be helpful,

My question is how do I create the model classes, suppose I have an table in the database, I understand that I cannot use the LINQtoSQL generated Class as the model class, if I do, then I would become dependent on LinqtoSQL, which inturn would take away the independence that I would have of implementing the repository pattern, does that mean that I would need to have my own custom classes for all entity classes?

Comment: You may want to consider alternatives to LinqToSql, which is not a great choice in this scenario, as you've found.

Comment: Out of curiosity, what did you decide here?

Comment: @Anderson, I decided to go ahead with your way.... no extra lubricating layer for this one, as it is small project, changes can be managed directly without much hassles...

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Good lord, no.  Why would you do that to yourself?

You've already got to duplicate so much in your ViewModels, why would you add another layer of duplication for so little gain, especially considering L2S can use plain ol' clr types?

I consider both my service contracts from WCF services and ORM types to *be* my model.  Just because it doesn't reside in a *.Model namespace doesn't mean a thing.

If you feel like you need this lubricating layer, let that layer be your ViewModels.  That's what they are there for.

Comment: I think I get what you are saying, put the ORM and services in the models and yeah... I too am a bit stunned by the amount of duplication that is going on here, will surely look into this, and let you know,, thanks Andy....

Comment: Thanks Again for your concern to ask again :)

Comment: and btw, it would have been real pains to duplicate the Model classes ... you saved me a lot of time,,,

Answer (score 1):

Yes, it means that you need to implement you own custom classes for all entity  classes. It's a pain, but that's the current state of things.

See [this SO answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1405665/how-should-i-handle-my-entity-domain-objects-using-ioc-dependency-injection/1409398#1409398) for more information on the subject, and some possible remedies.

Comment: "don't let the name of the generated L2S classes fool you." fits in perfectly, I also see that it would be better to write your custom classes offering you benefits like one could manage all the validation logic in that custom class, to point out one thing.