# C# MVC4 EF Ninject - repository in domain class

Tags: c#, entity-framework, ninject

I have a class:

```
Question
```

With the properties:

```
Bool IsTextAnswer
List<String> Answers
```

The answers to a question are:
2-4 answers stored in the list of answers OR
4 colors (stored in the db, for every question the same). The boolean decides if the answers are from the list or the colors.

The colors are just a table in the database with 4 rows, for every color a row.
These colors aren't linked to anything so I made a new repository: colorRepository from which I can get all the colors.

I did this in my code:
Constructor

```
public Question(IColorRepository colorRepository) {
   _colorRepository = colorRepository;
}
```

In the getter of the answers I try to do something like this:

```
if(IsTextAnswers) 
    return answers
return _colorRepository.FindAll
```

But ninject doesn't work because it's not a controller so I get the message that there is no parameterless constructor.

How can I retrieve my 4 colors from the database?

I only need the be able to read from the database, the questions + answers are made by an administrator in a java program.

Comment: Related: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1405665/how-should-i-handle-my-entity-domain-objects-using-ioc-dependency-injection

Comment: Related: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4835046/why-not-use-an-ioc-container-to-resolve-dependencies-for-entities-business-objec

Answer (score 1):

It looks like `Question` is an entity, and entity framework needs it to have a parameterless constructor.

Your repository should be a separate class, the domain objects should be POCOs and not have data access code in them.